# Select values in a table conditional to an external table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'd like to select the first N values of each variables (columns) in a data set, where N varies by column and row and are given in an other table. An example below with the iris data:

```
data(iris)
head(iris)
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

## Create a fake external table
ext.tab <- data.table(species=c("setosa","versicolor", "virginica" ),N1=c(1:3),N2=c(3:5),N3=c(5:7),N4=c(7:9))
head(ext.tab)

      species N1 N2 N3 N4
1:     setosa  1  3  5  7
2: versicolor  2  4  6  8
3:  virginica  3  5  7  9
```

Now for *Iris setosa*, I'd like to get the first maximum value (N1 in ext.tab) of column 1 ('sepal.length' in iris data), then the three max values (N2 in ext.tab) for column 2 (sepal.width), then the five max values (N3) for column 3 (petal.length) and so forth. Then moving to the *Iris versicolor* and do the same.

The result can be either a table or a list for each species with the values themselves or row indices for each variable (column). Any idea of a fast way to implement that?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What should your desired output look like?

Comment: Hi Wimpel. I have modified my answer to clarify the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach using a custom function. The function takes the variable and group names as character scalar and number of maximum values as numeric. Inside the function is a `dplyr` pipeline using [`.data` pronoun](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/tidyeval-data.html). Then, I reshaped `ext.tab` to long form and applied `get_maximum()` row-wise.

```
library(tidyverse)

get_maximum <- \(.x, .group, .n_max, .dat) {
  .dat %>% 
    filter(Species == .group) %>% 
    arrange(desc(.data[[.x]])) %>% 
    slice(seq_len(.n_max)) %>% 
    pull(.data[[.x]])
}


dat <- as_tibble(ext.tab) %>%
  pivot_longer(-species) %>%
  mutate(name = recode(
    name,
    N1 = "Sepal.Length",
    N2 = "Sepal.Width",
    N3 = "Petal.Length",
    N4 = "Petal.Width"
  )) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(max_num = list(
    get_maximum(name, species, value, iris)
  )) %>%
  ungroup()
```

If you need the unique maximum values, you can add `distinct()` inside the custom function.

```
get_maximum_unique <- \(.x, .group, .n_max, .dat) {
  .dat %>% 
    filter(Species == .group) %>% 
    distinct(.data[[.x]]) %>% 
    arrange(desc(.data[[.x]])) %>% 
    slice(seq_len(.n_max)) %>% 
    pull(.data[[.x]])
}
```

[image]

Comment: Whou! Thanks for your prompt answer Zaw. Looks like a very elegant solution! A few explanation along the code would have been a must.

Comment: In R 4.1.0, we can create a function using \. It was not the case in the earlier versions. You can use this instead. `get_maximum <- function(.x, .group, .n_max, .dat)`. You are right - should have added some explanations. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`. I have taken the liberty of renaming the column names.

```
cols <- setdiff(names(ext.tab), "Species")
iris[ext.tab, on=.(Species), by=.EACHI, 
    .(.(mapply(function(x, n) -head(sort(-x, partial=n), n), 
        x=mget(cols), n=mget(paste0("i.", cols)), SIMPLIFY=FALSE)))]$V1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
iris <- as.data.table(iris)
ext.tab <- data.table(Species=c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"),
    Sepal.Length=c(1:3),
    Sepal.Width=c(3:5),
    Petal.Length=c(5:7),
    Petal.Width=c(7:9))
```

output:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$Sepal.Length
[1] 5.8

[[1]]$Sepal.Width
[1] 4.4 4.2 4.1

[[1]]$Petal.Length
[1] 1.9 1.9 1.7 1.7 1.7

[[1]]$Petal.Width
[1] 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.4


[[2]]
[[2]]$Sepal.Length
[1] 7.0 6.9

[[2]]$Sepal.Width
[1] 3.4 3.3 3.2 3.2

[[2]]$Petal.Length
[1] 5.1 4.8 4.9 5.0 4.9 4.8

[[2]]$Petal.Width
[1] 1.7 1.6 1.6 1.8 1.5 1.5 1.6 1.5


[[3]]
[[3]]$Sepal.Length
[1] 7.7 7.9 7.7

[[3]]$Sepal.Width
[1] 3.8 3.8 3.6 3.4 3.4

[[3]]$Petal.Length
[1] 6.4 6.3 6.7 6.9 6.7 6.6 6.1

[[3]]$Petal.Width
[1] 2.5 2.5 2.4 2.5 2.4 2.4 2.3 2.3 2.3
```

Short explanation:

1. Perform a left join `iris[ext.tab, on=.(Species),`
2. `by=.EACHI` means for each row of `ext.tab`
3. `x=mget(cols)` gets the columns in `iris`
4. `mget(paste0("i.", cols))` gets the number of values required for each column
5. `-head(sort(-x, partial=n), n)` performs a partial sort and extract the first n values
6. `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` and `.(.( ))` are simply required to return the results as a list

Comment: Thanks! Looks also very nice. Sorry, I can accept only one answer. A few explanations would also have been helpful.